# Can someone explain the way this variable is declared?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and trying to modify a webiste template I bought and I am having a little difficulty understanding a certain way a variable is being declared/used.

The template has dynamic content funtions as JQuery extentions declared as such:

```
window.theme = {};

(function(theme, $) {

// function

}).apply(this, [window.theme, jQuery]);
```

Then in a seperate file they are initialized like this example:

```
(function($) {

    'use strict';

    if ($.isFunction($.fn['themePluginAnimate'])) {

        $(function() {
            $('[data-plugin-animate], [data-appear-animation]').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    opts;

                var pluginOptions = $this.data('plugin-options');
                if (pluginOptions)
                    opts = pluginOptions;

                $this.themePluginAnimate(opts);
            });
        });
    }
}).apply(this, [jQuery]);
```

The bit that is confusing me is:

```
var $this = $(this),
    opts;
```

It is my understanding from googling that this way of assignment with comma operator means:

```
$(this) = opts;
$this = $(this);
```

To my mind `opts` hasn't been initialized so how/why is it being used as an assignment?  This pattern is on every module so I want to understand it before I start making changes.

I did some googling and found that if `var = opt` was declared then it would have been hoisted but that is just for declaration not initialization.

Can someone point out to me what is going on here please?

Comment: `$this` is declared and assigned a value. `opts` is declared, but not assigned a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you need to explain how JavaScript init variables.
First of all when JavaScript reading you code - it moving all variables at the start of function:

```
function(){
  var a = 1;
  console.log(a);//1
  console.log(b);//undefined
  var b = 2;
}
```

will be look for JS like this:

```
function(){
   var a,b;//first of all we declare variables.
   a = 1;
   console.log(a);// => 1
   console.log(b);// => undefined
   b = 2;
}
```

But another function has more priority in the queue of declaring, thats why they will init earlier:

```
function(){
   console.log(func)// => function(){return 1;}
   console.log(a)// => undefined
   var a = 1;
   function fun(){return 1;}
}
```

and what really happened:

```
function(){
   function fun(){return 1;}//first of all functions
   var a;//secondary variables

   console.log(func)// => function(){return 1;}
   console.log(a)// => undefined
   a = 1;
}
```

it is a little theory for you, because I think you will meet something like this in code in the nearest future.

And now lets look for you code:

```
var $this = $(this),
    opts;
```

and how JavaScript read it?

```
var $this, opts;//declare all variables;

$this = $(this)//init variable $this
```

If you was confused by `,`, it's just delimiter between variables you declare:

```
var a,b,c,d;
```

is equal to:

```
var a;
var b;
var c;
var d;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, very useful to know that functions behave like that, I am sure that would have tripped me up eventually!

Answer (score 2):

```
var oneThing = 1, anotherThing;
```

Is just a shorthand for

```
var oneThing = 1;
var anotherThing;
```

Comment: Thank you, I read an answer that said it evaluated from right to left and misunderstood.

Comment: No problem. I dislike this shorthand syntax to be honest, because it's easy to misread.